# PHP の echo で改行されない

Tags: php

現在勉強中なのですが、echoで出力した文字列を改行しようと思いこのように書きました。

```
<?php
$atai=array
(       
    "改行１",
    "改行２",
    "改行３"       
);

for($i = 0 ; $i < count($atai); $i++){
        echo $atai[$i]."\n";
}
?>
```

しかし、コレでは改行されず調べてみた所、『OSによって改行コードが違う』と出てきました。

そのため、『改行コードを環境によって変える必要がある処理』である
PHP_EOLを使用して、下記のように書いたのですが上手くいきませんでした。

```
<?php
$atai=array
(
    "改行１",
    "改行２",
    "改行３"       
);

for($i = 0 ; $i < count($atai); $i++){
        echo $atai[$i].PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

これは、何故改行されなかったのでしょうか？

Comment: コンソールで実行していますか？

Comment: もしかして……HTMLで見て改行されていないと言うことですか？

Answer (score 2):

ブラウザ上で見た目を改行させたければ  `<BR>` タグを使う必要があります。